# How can I configure the colour of the dash?

Tags: unity, 12.04, unity-dash, colors

the new Ubuntu uses ugly colours merged out of my wallpaper. How can I turn this off, so it's just the darker version of the background (like in 11.10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Tweak Does a nice job recoloring the Dash

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: I don't see such an option in ubuntu-twek. Can you provide a path to the setting?